# Calling `mock.patch` before a `with` statement

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Could someone explain why `testAAA_with_patch_from_function_outside_with` fails, but the other two tests succeed?

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


class BBB:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def func1(self):
        print("func1 called")

    def func2(self):
        print("func2 called")

class AAA:
    def main_func(self):
        bbb1 = BBB("first case", 1)
        bbb1.func1()
        bbb1.func2()

        bbb2 = BBB("second case", 2)
        bbb2.func1()
        bbb2.func2()

class TestAAA(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.mock_bbb = unittest.mock.create_autospec(BBB)

    def testAAA(self):
        with mock.patch("test_example2.BBB") as patch_bbb:
            patch_bbb.return_value = self.mock_bbb
            aaa = AAA()
            aaa.main_func()
            self.assertEqual(2, self.mock_bbb.func1.call_count)
            self.assertEqual(2, self.mock_bbb.func2.call_count)

    def testAAA_with_patch_from_function(self):
        with self.setup_patch() as patch_bbb:
            patch_bbb.return_value = self.mock_bbb
            aaa = AAA()
            aaa.main_func()
            self.assertEqual(2, self.mock_bbb.func1.call_count)
            self.assertEqual(2, self.mock_bbb.func2.call_count)

    def testAAA_with_patch_from_function_outside_with(self):
        patch_bbb = self.setup_patch()
        with patch_bbb:
            patch_bbb.return_value = self.mock_bbb
            aaa = AAA()
            aaa.main_func()
            self.assertEqual(2, self.mock_bbb.func1.call_count)
            self.assertEqual(2, self.mock_bbb.func2.call_count)
            
    def setup_patch(self):
        return mock.patch("test_example2.BBB")
```

I don't see anything in the definition of the "with" statement that would make the last two tests semantically different, but is there something special about `mock.patch` that would make them behave differently?

Here's my motivation: I'm writing a number of unit tests that will all need the same patches, at least 6 of them.  I was hoping to put the patches in a helper function to avoid duplicating a big glob of patches on every unit test.  However, when I tried writing a function that returns a tuple of patches:

```
with setup_patches() as (patch_1, patch_2, patch_3...):
```

it failed because there's no `__enter__` on a tuple type.  So then I tried assigning variables outside the "with":

```
(patch_1, patch_2, patch_3...) = setup_patches()
with patch_1, patch_2, patch_3:
```

but this failed because apparently `mock.patch` works differently when it's used outside the `with` expression.  Is there any other way to simplify the patches?

Comment: Note that: *"If you use “as” then the patched object will be bound to the name after the “as”; very useful if patch() is creating a mock object for you."* (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). So in your two working tests, `patch_bbb` is a reference to the patch**ed** object. In the failing test, it's a reference to the `mock.patch` object itself.

Comment: If in your failing test you did `patcher = self.setup_patch()` then `with patcher as patch_bbb:` then it ought to work the same as the others.

Comment: Ah, I see... looking at the semantics of "with" more carefully, I need to work with the value of `enter(patch_bbb)` (or `enter(patcher)` using your suggested code) and not just `patch_bbb`... I see the difference now.  Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: I have never seen `with <variable>:` before, and it almost certainly doesn't have the semantics you're expecting.

Comment: @FrankYellin The `with` statement just needs a context manager; it doesn't matter if it comes from a simple name lookup or a more complicated expression. `with patch_bbb as foo:` would work just as well (switching to `foo` in the body, of course, noting the difference between the `patch` instance and what `patch.__enter__` returns.)